# Solve for a variable in mod

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I want to solve for $s=\frac{(M-x^y)}{r}$ mod $(p-1)$ where I know the values for $M,x,y,p,s$ but don't know $r$. How can I solve for $r$?

I tried to solve for $r$ by trying to compute $r=\frac{(M-x^y)}{s}$ mod $(p-1)$ in Maple but the correct values were not coming up.

Also if anyone know how to do this using any program that can handle large numbers (30-50 digits long), that would be a plus.

Comment: Is $s$ relatively prime to $p-1$?  Are you computing the inverse mod p-1 or attempting to simply divide as you would in the real numbers?

Comment: No, $s$ is not relatively prime to $p-1$. I am simply trying to solve for $r$ but don't know how to do so.

Comment: Are you working with integers?  Are you trying to find the integer that you multiply $s$ by to get $M-x^y$?

Comment: Yes, I am working with integers. I am trying to find the correct value for $r$ that when I divide $(M-x^y)$ by it and take the mod $(p-1)$, it gives me $s$, which is given.

Comment: You have to be careful with division, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply divide by $s$ on both sides; if $GCD(p-1,s)>1$ then you actually have $r\equiv\frac{M-x^y}{s}\pmod{\frac{p-1}{GCD(p-1,s)}}$.  At the same time, that equivalence should give you all solutions.